# git (lfs) clone hanging for image files when executed from java application

Tags: java, git, command, git-clone, git-lfs

In my Java application (running on Windows) I need to clone a git repository.
My command is:

```
<path_to_git>\bin\git.exe clone --depth 1 --branch <branch> <path_to_git_repo>.git <destination>
```

When I execute this command from cmd.exe everything is fine, git finishes and all my files are there.
However, when I execute this command from my Java application ie.

```
String cmd = <the above command>;
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

the following happens:

1. The download starts, I can see this in the task manager but also in the destination folder where most of the files are checked out
2. Download finishes, there is no network activity, the p.waitFor() call doesn't return and I have processes git.exe and git-lfs.exe still running
3. When using Procmon64.exe I see that git.exe and git-lfs.exe are working just as long I observer network activity, afterwards they don't do nothing at all.
4. A comparison of the working copy resulted from running the git clone from cmd.exe and the Java aopplication reveals there are no image files downloaded using the Java application

[image: comparison]

I guess it's something related to LFS but I have no clue how to debug this further. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `git clone` produces both stdout and stderr, both of which you should be consuming or a hang is likely if not inevitable

Comment: I do have this in my code but ie. BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); l1 = input.readLine(); but the readLine call hangs for both p.getInputStream() and p.getErrorStream()

Comment: Why only reading one line? Better post that code please. Edit the question

Comment: the code is basically a do-while loop that reads the process' inputstream until the line which is read is null. but it doesn't matter it's one call or multiple calls because the first readLine hangs.

Comment: ok found out the issue, see my comment below, thanks for the hint! However, I do have an issue now: how do you know what stream to consume at any time? Because consuming STDOUT in this situation brings you in a deadlock situation

Comment: Best practice is to consume stderr and stdout in dedicated thread to avoid deadlocks. Searching on 'StreamGobbler' would probably find you examples

Comment: in the end this is exactly what I did, created a thread for each and then assume the one which isn't going to be consumed at all will eventually get a -1

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally understood what's going on.
First, git has a bug that prints its cloning progress in STDERR instead of STDOUT.
My Java code that consumed the process output was initially:

```
char buffer[] = new char[1024];
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
int res;
do {
res = isr.read(buffer);
}while(res!=-1);
```

This initial version couldn't possibly work because the is.read() call would hang as no data was written to STDOUT.
Then I came up with:

```
char buffer[] = new char[1024];
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
InputStreamReader isre = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
int res,rese;
do {
rese = isre.read(buffer);
res = isr.read(buffer);
}while(res !=-1 || rese != -1);
```

This was also bad because while it did do something it didn't do before it still got stuck at isr.read. The isre.read would first unblock, get some data but then the isr.read would bring everything to a halt.

The correct code needs to only read STDERR:

```
char buffer[] = new char[1024];
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream());
int rese;
do {
rese = isr.read(buffer);
}while(rese!=-1);
```